# unable to permit a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to use active storage to to attach an image file to my photo model, but no matter what I try I get an error saying that the "image_file" is not permitted. I've found several other identical questions on Stack Overflow that are unanswered. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create ActiveStorage tables

```
rails active_storage:install
```

Add to Model

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image_file
end
```

Controller (permit :image_file)

```
def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:image_file)
end
```

Javascript for Direct Upload

```
//= require activestorage
```

Add Direct Upload to View

```
<%= f.file_field :image_file, class: 'form-control-file', direct_upload: true, required: true %>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you go into more detail about the last two steps?

Comment: It processes the upload in the browser - https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

Answer (score 0):

When I hit the byebug I entered "params" which returned `permitted: false` but I should have entered "photo_params which returns `permitted: true`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).